# Xcode xml parsing issue

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, xcode4, xml-parsing

I am creating an application in Xcode which parse xml but I have a problem in parsing this code

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/Sg8z_On_Jmc?fs=1" width="580" height="25"> <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Sg8z_On_Jmc?fs=1" /> <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> </object>
]]>
</description>
```

How can I get the URL in data or in value?

Thanks.

My source code: .M

//didStartElement at the beginning then;

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{

    if (![self currentStringValueTitle]) {

        [self setCurrentStringValueTitle:[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:50]];

    }

    if (![self currentStringValueImage]) {

        [self setCurrentStringValueImage:[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:50]];

    }


    if (![self currentStringValueDescription]) {

        [self setCurrentStringValueDescription:[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:50]];

    }


    [[self currentStringValueTitle] appendString:string];
    [[self currentStringValueDescription] appendString:string];
    [[self currentStringValueImage] appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Başlık: %@", [self currentStringValueTitle]);
    NSLog(@"Detay: %@", [self currentStringValueDescription]);

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{

   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] ) {

        [[self titleArray] addObject:[self currentStringValueTitle]];


    }
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"] ) {


        [[self descriptionArray] addObject:[self currentStringValueDescription]];


    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"description"] ) {

        [[self imageArray] addObject:[self currentStringValueImage]];
    } 


    [self setCurrentStringValueTitle:nil]; 
    [self setCurrentStringValueDescription:nil];
    [self setCurrentStringValueImage:nil]; 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind using [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) is that whatever is inside in it , it will be ignored by the parser... but thankfully NSXMLParser has an alternative for this...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

now someString is another xml string for you , which you can parse(this being an XML) using another instance of NSXMLParser... hoping this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have tried but it didn't work it push all the description line. I have edit my question and put my source code. Could you help me please.

Comment: I can tell you that you will require two instances of NSXMLParser.. just can write the full code here..

Comment: I couldn't edit the original post because it doesn't take more codes. So I published on this link;
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iuGDe7fDfkB8E9AzKliqh9KirMWJWLUBiZTiVV6ML2k/edit)

Thanks from now for help.